# how to do mutation in python? by reordering the original list

Tags: python, mutation

```
def swap_numbers(x, x_index): 
    for num in x:
        if x_index < len(x)-1:
            x[:] = x[:x_index] + [x[x_index+1]] + [x[x_index]]+ x[x_index+2:]
        elif x_index == len(x)-1:
            x[:] = [x[-1]] + x[1:-1] + [x[0]]
```

so if I want to mutate a list lets say x = [1,2,3,4,5] and x_index = 2
what this function does is swap the number of the index we input with the follows number.

It should be like

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> swap_numbers(x,2)
>>> x
[1,2,4,3,5]
```

but mine is

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> swap_numbers(x,2)
>>> x
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

however it works if I make the first part of function

```
x[:] = [x[:x_index] + [x[x_index+1]] + [x[x_index]] + x[x_index+2:]]"
```

it will then become

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> swap_numbers(x,2)
>>> x
[[1,2,4,3,5]]
```

what should I do?

Comment: what are `num` and `num_list`? are those supposed to be `x` and `x_index`?

Comment: uh...opps, thanks for telling me, already switched it :P

Comment: Why are your using a loop `for num in x:`?

Comment: @njzk2 lol never mind, I thought I would need it, I am a beginner to python so....haha that was a stupid mistake

Comment: your original cdde will work, i think, if you just remove the `for` line...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
def swap (l, i):
    l [i], l [i + 1] = l [i + 1], l [i]
```

This yields:

```
>>> def swap (l, i): l [i], l [i + 1] = l [i + 1], l [i]
... 
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> swap (a, 2)
>>> a
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

Comment: only issue is if i = len(l) - 1, as l[i+1] will throw exception

Comment: but if it's 'swap_numbers(x,4)' will the x becomes [5,2,3,4,1]?

Comment: I guess using `(i + 1) % len(l)` should fix it

Comment: `def swap (l, i): l [i], l [(i + 1) % len(l)] = l [(i + 1) % len(l)], l [i]`

Comment: That one would work too : `def swap (l, i): l [i], l [i + 1 - len(l)] = l [i + 1 - len(l)], l [i]`

Comment: oh, by the way, can I write "l[-1], l[0] = l[0], l[-1]"? instead of doing "l [i], l [i + 1 - len(l)] = l [i + 1 - len(l)], l [i]" aren't they the same?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do with an index error (the swap does not exist) but this works:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
def swap_numbers(li, ind):
    try:
        li[ind],li[ind+1]=li[ind+1],li[ind]
    except IndexError:
        pass       

swap_numbers(x,2)
print x   
# [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

This will just not do anything that cannot be done, like `swap_numbers(x,5)`

Comment: but if it's 'swap_numbers(x,4)' 
will the x becomes [5,2,3,4,1]?

Comment: No. If you do `swap_numbers(x,4)` x will not change